# How can I get the upload_id when uploading thumbnail for Youtube live stream creating?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building an application to automatically generate youtube live streams using cookies and urls (not using Google API).

In the thumbnail upload step, I see that the cURL looks like:
*https://upload.youtube.com/?authuser=0&upload_id=ABPtcPp6FrIQL38aGJBNsUd_UcY-uTg7a7QN0VjjPDiHpTr_fOZQ2dubWiLwRGoNTfgkmz8Fxjb3FS7cb94XJlYsFuusZueF17_gnQ 7OfCuEHZECAA&upload_protocol=resumable&origin=CjFodHRwczovL3VwbG9hZC55b3V0dWJlLmNvbS91cGxvYWQvc3R1ZGlvdGh1bWJuYWlsEkNibG9ic3RvcmUtaHR0cC1wcm9kLWdsb2JhbC15b3V0dWJ lLWRlZmF1bHQteW91dHViZS1zdHVkaW8tdGh1bWJuYWWW*

I checked browser's client-side javascript source code but didn't find a clue.

How can I get the upload_id to push into cURL?
Thanks everyone!